# Determining if time has influence on correlation between x and y

Tags: correlation, model-selection, model

Is there a sort of statistics model I could use to determine if time has an influence on the correlation between two sets of data? For example say I have a column $X$ and a column $Y$, both just columns of numbers, and then also a time column. Thus each row has time, $X$ and $Y$. Is there some sort of statistical analysis I could do that tells me if time has an influence on the relationship between $X$ and $Y$?

I ran across the Pearson Correlation Coefficient to measure correlation between two variables. I'm completely guessing here, but for example could I repeatedly use the Pearson Correlation for different segments of time, and then simply determine if there is a change in the Pearson Correlation Coefficients? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a statistical independence test, $I(X,Y|Z)$, to see if $X$ and $Y$ are independent given time, $Z$.

You may use probability to test for $I(X,Y|Z)$. If the following conditions holds, you know that $Z$ is some how blocking information between $X$ and $Y$.

$P(X,Y|Z) = P(X|Z)P(Y|Z)$

Additionally, since you are already using canonical Pearson correlation, you may try using partial correlations (conditional correlation).

$\rho_{XY\cdot Z } =
        \frac{\rho_{XY} - \rho_{XZ}\rho_{ZY}}
             {\sqrt{1-\rho_{XZ}^2} \sqrt{1-\rho_{ZY}^2}}$

Try here for starters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation regarding partial correlations.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Can you clarify what you mean by "Z is blocking information between X and Y"?

Comment: what i mean is that one way of looking at the problem is to think of the problem using graphical models. you may have the following relationships. 

X -> Z -> Y //X influences time, time influences Y
X <- Z <- Y //Y influences time, time influences X
X <- Z -> Y //time influences X and Y
X -> Z <- Y //X and Y influences time
X Z Y //no influences between X, Y and time

i would say, it is highly unlikely that anything can influence time (well, mass can influence spacetime, right)? basically, you are left with testing for the model X <- Z -> Y (time influences X and Y).

Comment: by "blocking information" i mean it in a graphical sense, if you condition on Z, does the correlation (information) between X and Y disappear? part of my response is based on information theory too (not just graphical models).